# How do I add multiple values to a field discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever I make a embed, the field can only contain one value. Im trying to make the embed like this.
[Flow music's help embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipr8c.png)

I tried to use enter but it only appears in the code.

```
if message.content.startswith('embedtest'):
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Joe")
      embed.add_field(name="joe", value="**joe**-joe", inline=True)
```

This is the embed I was trying to change. Answer does not require to be the same embed, I just need an explanation for how to do it.

Comment: I think what you actually want to do is add more fields, a field can only have one value

Answer (score 0):

You can't make multiple values for one field, but you can just add multiple fields in one embed. One way to do this is like this:

```
YourEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Joe")
YourEmbed.add_field(name="joe3", value="joe1")
YourEmbed.add_field(name="joe4", value="joe2")
```

**Note that the maximum number of fields on one embed is 25.**
Make sure to send the embed using `ctx.send(embed=YourEmbed)`.

Comment: I was trying to add multiple values ( or atleast find a way to make it look like it ). Since I cant do 
FieldName
value 
value
Because I dont want to show another field title. I found a solution which was just to use \n to add the space between.